# How to select a printer for entire job?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have an Access 2003 database, which has a form to print a series of reports based off what job the user selects. The query is within the VBA code as well, which looks at the job's cataloged parts and opens their corresponding reports.

Here's the code that does so, correctly:

```
Private Sub Print_Report_Click()

Dim default_cat As Dao.Database
Dim d As Dao.Recordset
Dim q As String


Set default_cat = CurrentDb
q = "SELECT DISTINCT CATALOG, USER3 FROM [_MASTER_UPLOAD] WHERE SerialNumber='" & Me.[SerialNumberSelection] & "'"
Set d = default_cat.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)
d.MoveFirst

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint

Do While Not d.EOF


Select Case d!USER3

  Case "COM"
     DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTCompressor", , , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"

  Case "CON"
     DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTCondenser", , , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"

  Case "CRV"
     DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTCapacityRegValve", , , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"

  Case "CV"
     DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTCheckValve", , , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"

  Case "etc..."

End Select

d.MoveNext

Loop

d.Close

End Sub
```

Basically now where my problem lies is in the printer selection `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint`. The popup appears and I can select whatever printer I want, however that selection only seems to effect the first report of the group (all the others go to the computer's default printer). Most likely, I'll print the reports out from our print room printer, or just convert them to PDFs, but this also means I can't hardcode it to always print to a specific location.

**How can I make my printer selection stay valid for all of the reports, preferably without having to run the acCmdPrint command for every single report in the same group?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This question is specified and continued here: [How to pass reference to combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330111/how-to-pass-reference-to-combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first result of googling [access vba select printer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336132(v=office.12).aspx) (just saying):

The easiest way, if your reports are set to print on the default printer, is to temporarily change the default printer:

```
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("myPrinterDeviceName")
DoCmd.OpenReport "FirstReport"
DoCmd.OpenReport "SecondReport"
' ...
Set Application.Printer = Nothing
```

If not, you can do it per report:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "FirstReport", View:=acPreview, WindowMode:=acHidden
Set Reports("FirstReport").Printer = Application.Printers("myPrinterDeviceName")
DoCmd.OpenReport "FirstReport", View:=acViewNormal
```

The linked page also has an example on how to present a list of available printers for selecting one.

```
Private Sub GetPrinterList(ctl As Control)
    Dim prt As Printer
    For Each prt In Printers
        ctl.AddItem prt.DeviceName
    Next prt
    ctl = Application.Printer.DeviceName
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem I with the first two options you listed are that you have the printer name hard coded. I won't always be able to print to the same printer, also the number of reports will differ based on the job. Like I said, using `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint` gets me a list of my printers and allows me to choose one, but that printer is only active for the first report. The next reports go to the default printer.

Comment: That was just an example for simplicity. Instead of `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint`, add a "Select printer" dropdown box to your form, as shown on the MSDN page. This is the printer device name you use. You have to adapt these methods to your needs, I didn't intend to write finished code for your exact situation.

Comment: So to answer my question, I can't temporarily set my default printer to the printer I selected by using `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint`?

Comment: I think no. To (temporarily) change the default printer, you need `Set Application.Printer = ...`

Comment: I was thinking about that... Could I do something like `Set Application.Printer = acCmdPrint.Value`?

Comment: No, `acCmdPrint` is just a constant (do a Shift+F2 with the cursor in it). You need the DeviceName from the `Application.Printers` collection.

Comment: And since it's not always going to be the same device, you're saying the easiest way to implement this is through a combobox selection. Meh, okay. Thanks though

Comment: could you visit the new link for help on creating a list of printers? I'm new to VBA and am getting confused for some reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330111/how-to-pass-reference-to-combobox