# How to pass reference to combobox?

Tags: ms-access, printing, combobox, vba

This is a continuation from a previous post of mine: [How to select a printer for entire job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311039/how-to-select-a-printer-for-entire-job), where I basically want to print a series of reports from a form in my Access database.

Which refers to this help doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336132(v=office.12).aspx

I'm trying to create the combobox with active printers in it in order to temporarily change the default printer for a series of documents. I'm tripped up on where it says "pass a reference to a ComboBox control"... How does one implement this?

Here's the code I have so far, where `cboPrinterSelect` is the combobox name:

```
Private Sub cboPrinterSelect_Load(Cancel As Integer)
    Call GetPrinterList
    ' I'm not sure about this next part either'
    cboPrinterSelect.Value = GetPrinterList.value
End Sub

'***************************************************
Private Sub cboPrinterSelect_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(cboPrinterSelect.ListIndex)
End Sub
'***************************************************

Private Sub GetPrinterList(ctl As Control)
    Dim prt As Printer
    For Each prt In Printers
        ctl.AddItem prt.DeviceName
    Next prt
    ctl = Application.Printer.DeviceName    
End Sub
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated code, which is still throwing an error (described in Andre's comments):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call GetPrinterList(Me.cboPrinterSelect)
End Sub

'*********************************************************

Private Sub cboPrinterSelect_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(cboPrinterSelect.ListIndex)

End Sub

'***************************************************************

Private Sub GetPrinterList(ctl As Control)

Dim prt As Printer
For Each prt In Printers
    ctl.AddItem prt.DeviceName
Next prt
ctl = Application.Printer.DeviceName

End Sub
```

Comment: cboPrinterSelect is this also the name of the form?

Comment: you have `Private Sub GetPrinterList(ctl As Control)` but you are not passing a control to it when you are calling it, `Call GetPrinterList`. You need to add `Call GetPrinterList(your_control_name)`

Comment: The name of the form is "_Print Series", cboPrinterSelect is only the combobox name. @ShaiRado, could you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Private Sub cboPrinterSelect_Load(Cancel As Integer) should this code be in the form load then?  and you don't have an arg and ctl is not optional, so will require one.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't know where else to put it... Maybe as After Update instead of Load? As I said, I'm trying to follow the directions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336132(v=office.12).aspx here and am getting confused

Comment: Have a quick read through about form events in access, it will give you detail and also the order they are called in.  I don't think that code will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part, the call of `GetPrinterList()`, must go into the `On Load` event of the **form**.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call GetPrinterList(Me.cboPrinterSelect)
End Sub
```

That should be all that's missing.

The default printer is pre-selected by this line:

```
ctl = Application.Printer.DeviceName
```

And make sure that cboPrinterSelect has a RowSourceType of **Value List**.

Comment: I keep on getting an error "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name" whenever I open my form.

Comment: Remove your `cboPrinterSelect_Load()`. If that doesn't help, update your question with your current code.

Comment: `_AfterUpdate()` must not have a `Cancel` argument, so remove that. You should never modify the sub declaration of events, they must have exactly the form as the code generator creates them.

Comment: Fantastic, the error is gone! Now all the printers are showing up, however it won't let me choose the printer I want to use (when I click on it, the default printer is still highlighted). I'm assuming I have to edit the `ctl = Application.Printer.DeviceName` line somehow...

Comment: No, that line is just an initial selection (but you can comment it out for testing). Perhaps your combobox is locked?

Comment: I think it's because I'm calling the printer list twice. I only need to call it upon upload, not in the combobox after update, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117120/discussion-between-cdomination-and-andre).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it will display all connected Printers in the combo_box in your User_Form.

```
Public Sub GetPrinters()

    ' Use a large array (supports up to 100 printers).
    ReDim result(100) As String
    Dim wshNetwork, allPrinters As Object

    ' Get the network object
    Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set allPrinters = wshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

    ' Printers collection has two elements for each printer.
    For i = 0 To allPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
        Print_Series.cboPrinterSelect.AddItem allPrinters.Item(i + 1)
    Next

    ' call your user form and combo box will have all active printers
    Print_Series.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this all I should need or do I need to save parts of the code I've already got?

Comment: @cdomination have you ran it ? did you get all the printers in your combo box ? I have used your variable names in the code

Comment: This is an Access form, not a userform. And Access has the `Application.Printers` collection, no need to recreate it.

Comment: If you want to join in the chat under Andre's post, maybe you could help with my strange issue